# Will DL360 Gen 8 servers fit in rails designed for DL360 Gen 7 servers?

Tags: hp, rackmount

Title says it all.

If I want to use a DL360 gen 8 server with rails labelled 364998-001 (which Google Tells me are for G7 servers), can they be made to work with a G8 server and if so with how much work?

(I don't have easy access to the rails to try them beforehand.  My guess is they won't work, but it would be nice if they did - and I can certainly imagine a world where they would fit)

Comment: Racks are not designed for servers. Racks follow a standard (19 inch) and have a length - looking up the length is basically all that is variable. Learn your basics. You really ask whether a newer Mercedes will drive on a road designed for an older one.

Comment: @TomTom I believe the question is if a set of G7 rails will fit a G8 server.

Comment: Nope. That may be the question he WANTED to ask, it is not the question he ASKED. Also, would be a trivial question for essentially the manufacturer support.

Comment: @tomtom vidarlo is correct as to what I am asking - and I can see he has modified my question.  I don't have support from the manufacturer  (and anyway G8 servers are EOL as of 13 June 2021)

Comment: @TomTom At times it's possible to try an *reasonable* interpretation of questions, and not only the literal one...

Comment: Well, anyhow - off topic. Fits a product recommendation. Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Short: No, they need different one.

I've researched a bit, and i even know this out of my brain. G6 and G7 had the same Railmount. But in Fact, G8 had a different one.

HP - 679365-001 is the Part number for G8
HP - 487244-001 is the Part number for G6/G7

Comment: `HP - 679365-001` is also compatible with G9 & G10.

Comment: thanks, I stopped my further notice as it was not on topic